# Youtube data api v3 search.list query maximum length?

Tags: google-api, youtube-data-api

what is the allowed maximum length of q in the following youtube data api search call? is there any restriction on the number of terms allowed in q? https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&q=football

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is one defined

> [q](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) The q parameter specifies the query term to search for.
>
> Your request can also use the Boolean NOT (-) and OR (|) operators to exclude videos or to find videos that are associated with one of several search terms. For example, to search for videos matching either "boating" or "sailing", set the q parameter value to boating|sailing. Similarly, to search for videos matching either "boating" or "sailing" but not "fishing", set the q parameter value to boating|sailing -fishing. Note that the pipe character must be URL-escaped when it is sent in your API request. The URL-escaped value for the pipe character is %7C.

However your going to have to consider the max length of a query string in the browser.

> RFC 3986 also states there is no limit, but indicates the hostname is limited to 255 characters because of DNS limitations (section 2.3.3). Microsoft states that the maximum length of a URL in Internet Explorer is 2,083 characters, with no more than 2,048 characters in the path portion of the URL.May 2, 2009